# TFS 2010 - How to make all work items inaccessible for a specific TFS project

Tags: tfs, permissions

I am trying to figure out how to modify the work items permissions on a specific TFS project to inaccessible?

I want to make the work items 'invisible' to all users.

The MSDN documentation is a little unclear (at least for a newbie):
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms252587.aspx

it mentions **TFSSecurity** could be used from command line and I think i need to deny WORK_ITEM_READ for that project - could someone provide the syntax for that?

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with TFSSecurity.  But unless you enjoy command line pain, just use Team Explorer (via Visual Studio).

Right click on a project in Team Explorer and select "Team Project Settings"  then select "Areas and Iterations".

In the resulting dialog make sure that the root Area (called "Area") is selected then select the "Security" button in the bottom of the dialog box (next to close).

That will launch the security options for the work items under that Area.  From there you can uncheck "View work items in this node" for everyone in the list.

However you will be unable to remove Collection admin's rights to view the work items.  You may be able to do that via TFSSecurity.exe but it would be abnormal to do so.